# How to align table so that it doesn't overflow the page horizontally

Tags: tables

I need this to fit in page, but it overflows! I tried reference on the link

1. [How to shrink a table automatically so that it fits onto a page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63651/how-to-shrink-a-table-automatically-so-that-it-fits-onto-a-page)
2. [Latex table goes out of page border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245382/latex-table-goes-out-of-page-border)

but no success.
Here's the table.

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|1|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
 ID & Test Name & Test Description & Input & Expected Output & Actual Output \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline
 1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\ 
 \hline
 1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \hline
1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \hline
1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\tabcap{Sound Limit in different zones}
\end{center}
```

Comment: How is the `\tabcap` macro defined? And, did you mean to write `l` ("ell") rather than `1` ("one") in the argument of `\begin{tabular}`?

Comment: `l` (not (`1`) and `c` are single line entries: perhaps you want `p{3cm}` to allow line breaking but you ask how to make the table fit without giving any indication of the size that it needs to fit into. Please always post a complete small docuemnt that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two solutions based on `tabularx`. The second uses the `booktabs` package, with only $3$ horizontal rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, caption, tabularx,  ragged2e,  booktabs}

\begin{document}\

\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|c|*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|}}
  \hline
  ID & Test Name & Test Description           & Input                & Expected Output              & Actual Output   \\ [0.5ex]
  \hline
  1  & Arduino   & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED \\
  \hline
  1  & Arduino   & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED \\
  \hline
  1  & Arduino   & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED \\
  \hline
  1  & Arduino   & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Sound Limit in different zones}
\vskip1cm

\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lc*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}}
  \toprule
  ID & Test Name & Test Description           & Input                & Expected Output              & Actual Output   \\ [0.5ex]
  \midrule
  1  & Arduino   & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED \\
  \addlinespace
  1  & Arduino   & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED \\
  \addlinespace
  1  & Arduino   & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED \\
  \addlinespace
  1  & Arduino   & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{Sound Limit in different zones}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: does \documentclass{} matter?

Comment: I want table to continue in second page, when I use \newpage it gives back an error. any ideas?

Comment: can you explain in english what your solutions do please?

Comment: @CharlieParker: It's pretty simple: as I use `tabularx`, columns 3 to 6 have  a fixed width, calculated by latex, so that table has an overall width equal to `\linewidth`. Thus, these columns are in paragraph mode,. Further, I ask they use the `\RaggedRight` layout defined by the `ragged2e` package. Is that clear? (B.t.w., do you play alto saxophone like Bird?)

Answer (score 6):

Short of totally reformulating your table, there are several possible steps that can help, as shown below:

1) You can reduce the font size of the table

2) You can reduce the blank padding of each column by respecifying  the length `\tabcolsep`.

3) If symmetric margin overrun is permitted (it is in my organization), you can place the tabular into a `\makebox` of width less than or equal the `\textwidth`, which will force any margin overlaps to be symmetrically distributed left and right, rather than run off the right margin.

Here is the MWE.  Note: since `\tabcap` macro was not provided, I changed over to `\captionof` of the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \tabcolsep=1pt\relax
 \small% <<--- CAN USE \footnotesize OR \scriptsize IF NEEDED
\captionof{table}{Sound Limit in different zones}
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
 ID & Test Name & Test Description & Input & Expected Output & Actual Output \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline
 1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\ 
 \hline
 1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \hline
1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \hline
1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}}
%\tabcap{Sound Limit in different zones}
\end{center}\medskip
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

While there are ways of scaling the `tabular` content to precisely fit the text margins, I do not recommend such an approach in general, because it means that each oversized table is presented it its own unique font size.  If there is more than such table in a document, it can be visually jarring to see a different scale factor for each table.

Comment: not sure if there is a magic number but `\tabcolsep=3.2pt\relax` worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you (a) use a `tabularx` environment -- with width set to `\textwidth` -- instead of a `tabular` environment, (b) use a raggedright version of the `X` column type for columns 3 thru 6, and (c) reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace. You may also want to think about  removing all vertical bars and using fewer (but well-spaced) horizontal bars in order to give the table a more open look.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\caption{Sound Limit in different zones}
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} ll *{4}{L} @{}} 
 \toprule
 ID & Test Name & Test Description & Input & Expected Output & Actual Output \\ [0.5ex]
 \midrule
 1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\ 
 \addlinespace
 1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \addlinespace
1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \addlinespace
1 & Arduino & Code burning and executing & Pin controlled write & blinking LED on intended pin & Blinking of LED\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```